# FloatingActionButton from support library causes an exception. Why?

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button

I have the following layout activity_fab.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_info_outline_white_36dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My ActivityFab.java

```
package com.example.testandroidsupportv7;

import com.example.testandroidsupportv7.R;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ActivityFab extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setTheme(R.style.MyTheme_NoActionBar);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fab);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // method not found toolbar.setElevation(25);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(40);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is a very simple example. But, it still crashes with the following output from logcat:

```
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testandroidsupportv7/com.example.testandroidsupportv7.ActivityFab}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at com.example.testandroidsupportv7.ActivityFab.onCreate(ActivityFab.java:18)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     ... 11 more
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     ... 23 more
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper from class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:133)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:110)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     ... 26 more
```

From what I can see the problem is in the:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper from class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:133)
01-27 20:09:52.184: E/AndroidRuntime(4067):     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:110)
```

If I try to import this class into code with

```
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper;
```

I cannot, because the type is not visible. Does this mean that my version of suuport library (23.0.1) has something wrong with access modifiers?
Why does this error happen? How to fix?

EDIT:
On popular demand I am posting also my styles and theme.

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

    -->
    <style name="MyThemeActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.

        -->
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.

        -->
        <item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/selector_selectable_background</item>
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    </style>

    <!-- styles -->


    <!-- textColor, textColorHint za EditText NE GRE NASTAVIT v android:textAppearance -->
    <style name="EditText" parent="">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.EditText</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/selector_input_text_light</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/selector_input_hint_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
        <item name="android:minWidth">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">80dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">80dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.SpinnerItem</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextInputLayout" parent="">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/selector_input_hint_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Test" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">?colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">?colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">?colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">?colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Text Appearance -->
    <!-- textColor, textColorHint za EditText cannot be set in android:textAppearance -->
    <style name="TextAppearance.EditText" parent="">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.SimpleColor" parent="">
        <item name="android:textColor">#aa0000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.SpinnerItem" parent="">
        <item name="android:textColor">#aa0000</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

UPDATE:

I have googled for source code of AppCompatImage helper class at [android.googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper.java). The class definition starts with:

```
    .
    .
    .
import static android.support.annotation.RestrictTo.Scope.GROUP_ID;
/**
 * @hide
 */
@RestrictTo(GROUP_ID)
public class AppCompatImageHelper {
    private final ImageView mView;
    . 
    .
    .
```

Is it possible that this @RestrictTo(GROUP_ID) annotation restricts visibility of class?
And a subquestion arose? How to find source code for specific version of support library?

Comment: Can you post your app-level `build.gradle`?

Comment: I am not using gradle. Still eclipse. Android studio is way to slow to be usable.

Comment: You may be out of luck then. Google [dropped support](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html) for Eclipse in 2015. Either way, my initial thoughts are you may need the base support library in addition to the design support library, if you haven't already included it.

Comment: What makes you stay on Eclipse , aren't you tired of being an eclipse Engineer , Eclipse has issues , my man update to Android studio please, otherwise we might find you in the After life LOL

Comment: @Lutaaya There are some reasons we stay on this version of support library, As far is eclipse is concerned ozr testing of android studi was very unsatisfactory. Slow, some missing features, slow, it uses a lot of ram so it is hard to have all the other stuff open one needs and, did I say android studio is very slow.

Comment: @MichaelDodd Yes, I have all the other modules of support library.

Comment: @Daniel I do not use gradle build system, so therefore there is no project properties configuration. What I use is eclipse with ant. I suspect you think I am missin some library reference (dependency): I don't think so. It looks to me that AppCompatImageHelper is missing from the library. Other classes are present. To me it smells like a wrong acces modifier, protected instead of public or something like that.

Comment: Please post your styles.xml

Comment: @user6694745, well for the issue of android studio being slow, i defy that , android studio is currently fast as long as you have 4 or 8gb and above , you try it one day , me i was also using eclipse and i loved it so much , but i realised that Eclipse , has alot of issues , it takes much time when you are repairing it

Comment: Now you see , you just struggling with a floating action bar , but in android studio , there's just an inbuilt template , you just start an activity with it and you walk away smartly smiling without wasting time, but you see now what you are on , time is going instead of making other relevant research , me my advice will still remain migrate to android studio

Comment: @Lutaaya Once again. Migration at his point in time is not possible. Android Studio is not mature to be used in production. If everything else would be ok it os just to slow to allow development.

Comment: @user6694745 RE: "not mature to be used in production", anecdotal, but I very much disagree. The company I work for manufactures an Android-based deskphone (we make changes to AOSP as well as writing apps on top). We all use Android studio on a mix of Windows 10 and Linux machines and generally have no issues other than the occasional temporary lockup when AS is trying too many sync operations at once.